# Can't connect to Minio which is on local vm server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, minio

Colleagues, hello everyone, in nginx, and even more so MinIO, I'm not strong yet, I ran into such a problem. I have a server that is accessible via a white IP, a virtual machine with the address `10.10.10.50` is deployed on this server, I deployed MinIO on this VM. There is Nginx on the server that forwards traffic at `10.10.10.50:9000`, I used the Nginx config from the official MinIO website, but when connected, it gives an error:
`Page is not available. The MinIO site did not send data.`

MinIO works 100% forwarded VPN to the server, from the server network the site at `http://10.10.10.50:9000` is available. For the third day I've been racking my brains, I've given up.

Server on Debian11

nginx config

```
server {
   listen       80;
   listen  [::]:80;
   server_name  minio;

   # Allow special characters in headers
   ignore_invalid_headers off;
   # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
   # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
   client_max_body_size 0;
   # Disable buffering
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_request_buffering off;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_connect_timeout 300;
      # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      chunked_transfer_encoding off;

      proxy_pass http://10.10.10.50:9000/; # This uses the upstream directive definition to load balance
   }
}
```

There is no firewall, there are no errors in the Nginx log, I noticed that when using the curl command, an error is generated `AccessDenied`

And also noticed that when contacting the site, minio redirects to the internal port, but then the site is not available